# initializer list to initialize std::vector<std::function<bool(std::string)> > gives error with g++ 4.9.0 but compiles fine with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11, initializer-list

The following reduced case will compile and run fine in MSVS 13, but with gcc 4.9.0 I get the error:

> cannot convert from `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to `std::vector(std::function<bool(std::string)>>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string>  

template<typename F> class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a) : wombat(a) {};
    ~Foo() {}

    bool get_result() { return result; }

protected:
    template<typename A> bool do_something(std::string& s, A& a, A b, A c);

    bool result;
    int wombat;
};

template<typename F> template<typename A> bool Foo<F>::do_something(std::string& s, A& a, A b, A c)
{
    if ( a > b && a < c)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

struct Tim
{
    int age;
    float weight;
};

class Bar : public Foo<Tim>
{
public:
    Bar(int a) : Foo<Tim>(a) {};
    ~Bar() {};

    void do_somethings();
};

void Bar::do_somethings()
{
     Tim t;
     t.age = 15;

     std::vector<std::function<bool(std::string)> > my_list = {
         std::bind(&Bar::do_something<int>, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(t.age), 10, 100)
     };   // Error shows up here

     for( auto v : my_list) { result = v("howdy"); }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Bar b(200);
    b.do_somethings();
    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or miss something about how initializer lists are supposed to work?

Comment: @Praetorian, sorry, the computer I have the compilers on is not connected to the internet, so I have to by hand retype the example.

Comment: I do not believe this is a minimal example.  Or anywhere close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename A> bool do_something(std::string& s, A& a, A b, A c)
```

The type of `do_something`'s first parameter is `std::string&`, not `std::string`. Change the parameter type of the `std::function` accordingly.

```
std::vector<std::function<bool(std::string&)> > my_list = ...
//                                        ^
```

For the same reason, you cannot invoke the `std::function` instance as `v("howdy")` because that involves the construction of a temporary `std::string` object, which cannot bind to a non-`const` lvalue reference parameter. Use this instead

```
std::string s("howdy");
for( auto v : my_list) { result = v(s); }
```

Another option would be to change the function parameter type to `std::string const&` if it doesn't need to modify the argument.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b05571294ba79b0d)

---

Also be aware that you're making a copy of each vector element in the `for` loop. You may want to change that to

```
for( auto& v : my_list)
```